# Why, My site doesn't show logo title after loading

Tags: wordpress, caching, title

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt60E.jpg)
**

### My title logo not appear after page load in header section

**.
I have checked all the settings but I can't ...
After disabling LiteSpeed Cache plugin ...Logo appear but My site speed very slow..
So. I can't disabling LiteSpeed Cache plugin.
What I do??

Comment: Can you provide us with URL of the site? Can you access the logo image by directly putting in the URL for the image?

If you include a logo image in some post or on a page, does it show up?

Comment: https://rajatabhijeet.com site name

Comment: I can see your logo without any problem, both on mobile devices and destop computer. I can see that it is located at https://rajatabhijeet.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Rajatabhijeet-191x64.png

In my experience, no plugin can replace a good hosting server.

Comment: Enable the cache plugin again, and make sure the page loads fine with the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with URL of the site? Can you access the logo image by directly putting in the URL for the image?

If you include a logo image in some post or on a page, does it show up?